# 'Options' object has no attribute 'getallrelated_objects' after Wagtail 1.11.1 Upgrade

Tags: wagtail

Just upgraded to 1.11.1, all fine locally but on our server we're getting

wagtail AttributeError: 'Options' object has no attribute 'getallrelated_objects'

on the new admin page navigation menu

Any idea?

Thanks

Joss

Answer (score 0):

I had to bump up djangorestframework to 3.6.3, this fixed the error